# ionic react: how to change the size of grid on click

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

i'm trying to use ionic react framework for a app. I have a requirement where i have grid with 1 row and 2 columns. the first column takes 75% and second column takes 25% of screen. When i click on the 25% column then it should become 75% and the first column should be 25%.

i tried to use on-click event on the grid column , but not sure how to use on-click for grid columns to change the size of columns dynamically. Instead of using a grid is there any other way to get the same experience?

Answer (score 0):

You don't use on-click for grid tags. You need to bind the size attribute like so:

```
<ionCol [size]="logic_here">
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/grid